# Slides hang up when revisiting its parent Tab in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this slides in my Home page (the first tab in my Ionic 3 app):

```
   <ion-slides *ngIf="someProducts.length" effect='slide' loop="true" autoplay=2000 pager speed=1000>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of someProducts"> 
        <img class="banner-img-class" [src]=product.picture/>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Every thing works fine when starting the app, but when I leave the current tab (home) to another one and get back to it, the sliding is frozen.

Is there any workaround to make it sliding, because I searched but in vain.

**BTW**: product.picture is a url to a firebase storage located image.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible. This is why it's not recommended to put slides component inside a Tab

Comment: Yeah, apprently you are perfectly right, is their any recommandation please? A replacement of slides with good user experience, but I have to keep tabs

Comment: The only advice I know  is that you put your slides component in a page & That you call your page with push method or setRoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, do not put slides in Ionic Tab, it's incompatible.